# Skip CloudFront cache for a request with session data

Tags: node.js, express, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I'm running a NodeJS app (via [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com)) on EC2. I have an AWS CloudFront distribution pointing at the app.

I'm using [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) for the app to record a shopping basket. I have CloudFront configured to whitelist the session cookie, but requests to the shopping basket page are cached and not routed to the origin. When I add an item to my basket, it seems to work (eg. it increments a counter in the session store), but when reloading the page, the request never touches the origin server and so I don't see the basket.

I'm not sure how I should approach this: I've set CloudFront to pass on my cookies, but the `set-cookie` header is only provided when I first add an item to my basket (eg. this is what CloudFront varies caching on).

I don't want to simply save a cookie on every session request as this will effectively kill my caching. What's the best way to handle this case? I need this shopping basket page to skip the cache if there's session data, basically. Do I simply check for `req.session` and return a `no-cache` header? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Hmm, I just tried adding the latter option (setting a `Cache-Control` of 0 if `req.session` exists) but Cloudfront caches the first request to the basket with my default `Cache-Control` of 300. Do I just need to not cache this entire page, then?

Comment: If you're whitelisting the session cookie, you'll just have a cache entry for the page with the session cookie value? Subsequent requests to the page, on the same session, will be served by the CloudFront cache - right? I'd take the approach of ensuring all requests through to the shopping-basket page, or the underlying datasource (e.g. JSON) aren't cached (whitelist all headers).

Comment: If you are forwarding the session cookie to the origin, then requests made with the cookie should never receive a response that was cached as a result of a request made without it.  Once you started sending `Cache-Control: private` when the cookie was present, this should have "just worked" ... assuming you *also* sent `Cache-Control: private` with the response that originally sets the cookie...